# What are some Alternatives to Gitk that can be used in Windows Powershell?

Tags: git, powershell, gitk

I'm using windows powershell to manage git, but am limited in that it can't seem to run the Gitk command.  (At least by default)

Are there any other tools I can use from PS or is there a way I can force PS to interpret the Gitk launch script correctly?

Comment: I think if you have [Tcl/Tk](http://tcl.tk) installed, you should be able to run `wish path\to\gitk`. No experience with PowerShell, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make sure `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\gitk` or  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\gitk.cmd` ( change as per where you installed MSYSGIT) is in PATH

Comment: This is correct!  Though with PowerShell, I've actually got to type gitk.cmd in order to start the DIFF gui.  I may be able to set an alias for that, but at least I've got it all in the same terminal window now.  Thanks!  (**EDIT** yes, you can set an alias to gitk.cmd, all is right with the world)

Answer (score -1):

I'm a big fan of using Mercurial and Tortoise HG - http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/ - from PowerShell. A Google came up with this link for Tortoise Git https://tortoisegit.org/